# How to read only some sections of a config file

Tags: python, config

I want to access client_name, client_id and payment_id for each of the clients in the client list in order to start start a few processed using multithreading. I have included my config file and the way I am trying to access it. I found how to iterate over all sections, but don't know how to access just some of them. Any help is appreciated.

```
cfg = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
cfg.read('config.ini')
customer_url=cfg.get('general', 'url')

 
def process(client_name, client_id, payment_id):
    print("process()")
    clients=cfg['clients']
    client_list=cfg['clients']['client_list']
    

    for client in client_list:
        
       
       client_name = cfg.get(clients,'client_name')
       client_id=cfg.get(clients, 'client_id')
       payment_id =cfg.get(clients, 'payment_id')
       
    
    for _ in range(len(clients[client_list])):
         thread=threading.Thread(target=process, args=[client_name, client_id, payment_id])
         thread.start()
```

```
[clients]
client_list= xxx, yyy,zzz

[general]

DB_HOSTNAME = localhost
DB = asass
DB_USERNAME =asasasas
DB_PASSWORD = ddddddd
DB_PORT = 3307
url=https://something.com

[xxx]
client_name = xxx
client_id = 24
payment_id = 26



[yyy]
client_name = yyy
client_id = 12
payment_id = 45


[zzz]
client_name = zzz
client_id = 4545
payment_id = 46
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look them up, since you have the keys:

```py
clients=[x.strip() for x in cfg['clients']['client_list'].split(",")]
for client in clients:
    details = cfg[client]
    do_stuff(details)
```

Or do the lookup in the listcomp:

```py
clients = [cfg[x.strip()] for x in cfg["clients"]["client_list"].split(",")]
for client in clients:
    do_stuff(client)
```

With that said there are some very odd things about your code.  Don't launch a thread by pointing it to the current function---that creates infinite recursion.  I've no idea why you want to multithread this anyhow.  Certainly just parsing the data shouldn't be threaded: it'll take longer to set up/serialise than just to do it sequentially.

Comment: Thank you. When I try your suggestions I get an error: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'SectionProxy' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @user19441790 oops, didn't look at the .ini file carefully enough, I wanted to look up the list, so it's `cfg["clients"]["client_list"]`.  Corrected.

Comment: Thank you! It works now and I added it above the function, so it would not call itself recursively.